# Split sheet into multiple sheets based on range of values in columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel to split a sheet like the following into multiple sheets based on some criteria (priority)

[image]

[image]

For example the sheet (priority: very high) may look like this:
[image]

I am using number filter in Excel to filter the sheet and copy the filtered results into a new sheet.

How can I make the workflow simpler, like building a VBA program inside Excel?

Comment: @katz Thanks for your attention. I solved it, the answer is written below.

Answer (score 1):

This macro should work. But prior to running it, the sheet you want to split must be the ACtive Sheet, and you will have to create new, blank sheets called "Priority - Very High", "Priority - High", "Priority - Low" and/or "Priority - Very Low" (depending on what split you want to do at the time):

```
Sub Splitsheets()
Dim Priority As String

Priority = InputBox("Enter the priority (Very High, High, Low or Very Low)")

If Priority = "Very High" Then
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:D")
         .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=5"
         .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<5"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("Priority - Very High").Range("A1")

ElseIf Priority = "High" Then
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:D")
         .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<5"
         .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<5"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("Priority - High").Range("A1")

ElseIf Priority = "Low" Then
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:D")
         .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=5"
         .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=5"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("Priority - Low").Range("A1")

ElseIf Priority = "Very Low" Then
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:D")
         .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<5"
         .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=5"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("Priority - Very Low").Range("A1")
End If

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I actually find out a way to solve this problem:
Not very efficient, but it is easy to understand.

```
Sub VeryHigh()
Dim LastRow As Long

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Very High Priority"


Sheets("Very High Priority").UsedRange.Offset(0).ClearContents
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=">=5"
    .Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="<5"
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("Very High Priority").Range("A1")

End With
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End Sub

Sub High()
Dim LastRow As Long

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "High Priority"


Sheets("High Priority").UsedRange.Offset(0).ClearContents
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="<5"
    .Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="<5"
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("High Priority").Range("A1")

End With
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End Sub

Sub Low()
Dim LastRow As Long

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Low Priority"


Sheets("Low Priority").UsedRange.Offset(0).ClearContents
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=">=5"
    .Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=">=5"
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("Low Priority").Range("A1")

End With
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End Sub
Sub VeryLow()
Dim LastRow As Long

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Very Low Priority"


Sheets("Very Low Priority").UsedRange.Offset(0).ClearContents
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="<5"
    .Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=">=5"
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("Very Low Priority").Range("A1")

End With
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End Sub
```